# How do I solve this partial derivative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Find the partial derivatives of the function $f(x,y,z)=(x+2y)^2 \sin(xy).$

I know the answers are:

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = y(x + 2y)^2\cos(xy) + 2(x + 2y)\sin(xy)$

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = x(x + 2y)^2\cos(xy) + 4(x + 2y)\sin(xy)$

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = 0$

But I can't figure out why. I would really like to see the working for these and to know what background areas I would need to study to be able to do them myself.  Thanks.

Comment: There is nothing to solve here, but only Partial Derivatives to be evaluated. It is not correct to use "Solve" in this context.

Comment: @Arjang in what contexts is it correct to use solve?

Comment: In general when an equation is put in terms of one of the variables, because generally solve means "Solve for x,y, etc." in this case if the above 3 partial derivatives as given and was asked what is $f(x,y,z)$ then you'd be solving the system of equation for $f(x,y,z)$. Another way to look at this is that differentiation is a process and is being applied to the function, not requiring one to figure out the process that would give the answer. if the question was $f(x,y,z)=1$ solve for $x,y,z$ then one has to figure out the process to find all the values x,y,z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To partially differentiate, treat all other variables as constants and use the standard rules for differentiation.  For instance for the last result, since $z$ does not appear in the definition of $f$, the entire term is a constant and its derivative is zero.  For the other two, use the [product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule), [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule), and that $\partial sin(x)/\partial x = cos (x)$

Answer (score 1):

From product rule
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}= & \frac{\partial(x+2y)^{2}}{\partial x}\sin(xy)+(x+2y)^{2}\frac{\partial(\sin(xy))}{\partial x}\\
= & 2.(x+2y).1.\sin(xy)+(x+2y)^{2}.y.\cos(xy)\\\end{align*}
$$

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}= & \frac{\partial(x+2y)^{2}}{\partial y}\sin(xy)+(x+2y)^{2}\frac{\partial(\sin(xy))}{\partial y}\\
= & 2.(x+2y).2.\sin(xy)+(x+2y)^{2}.x.\cos(xy)\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}= & 0
\end{align*}
$$